# Does Percona Xtrabackup support RedHat release 4

Tags: mysql, percona, backup, xtrabackup

I downloaded Percona's Xtrabackup rpm file for RedHAT. I attempted to install but hit into an error. The error seems to point to missing dependencies and libraries. I have no issue with RedHat 6 OS. I could not find the binaries in Percona's website for RedHat4.

Is it supported in RedHat 4? Possible for a workaround?

`rpm -Uvh percona-xtrabackup-2.2.9-5067.el6.x86_64.rpm
warning: only V3 signatures can be verified, skipping V4 signature
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.10)(64bit) is needed by percona-xtrabackup-2.2.9-5067.el6.x86_64
        libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.0)(64bit) is needed by percona-xtrabackup-2.2.9-5067.el6.x86_64
        perl(DBD::mysql) is needed by percona-xtrabackup-2.2.9-5067.el6.x86_64
        rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by percona-xtrabackup-2.2.9-5067.el6.x86_64
        rtld(GNU_HASH) is needed by percona-xtrabackup-2.2.9-5067.el6.x86_64
        rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by percona-xtrabackup-2.2.9-5067.el6.x86_64
    Suggested resolutions:
        /var/spool/up2dateperl-DBD-MySQL-2.9004-3.1.x86_64.rpm`

Answer (score 0):

Percona XtraBackup 2.2 does not seem to have support out of the box for Red Hat 4:

> Supported Releases
>
> The CentOS repositories should work well with Red Hat Enterprise Linux
>   too, provided that yum is installed on the server.
>
> ```
> CentOS 5 and RHEL 5
> CentOS 6 and RHEL 6
> CentOS 7 and RHEL 7
> Amazon Linux AMI (works the same as CentOS 5)
> ```

Try, however, first the [generic Linux binary](http://www.percona.com/downloads/XtraBackup/XtraBackup-2.2.9/binary/tarball/percona-xtrabackup-2.2.9-5067-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz) and see if you can at least run the xtrabackup binary.

If not, you can either try to compile it by yourself (it shouldn't be too difficult in terms of dependencies, but Xtrabackup is a monster source and you may en up in dependency hell) or hire their paying support/development so they can make it work for you (they have great engineers).

Comment: I did try the **generic Linux binary** and hit into libraries compilation error.

`./xtrabackup
./xtrabackup: error while loading shared libraries: requires glibc 2.5 or later dynamic linker`